# Concatenar o que for igual e separar o que for diferente com MYSQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Bom, acredito que vá ficar um pouco confuso talvez, mas preciso fazer o seguinte:
Em um tabela exemplo estou inserindo vários nomes na coluna nome, no qual muitos desses nomes são iguais, gostaria de juntar todos os nomes iguais em uma query, e os que forem diferentes em outra.
Por exemplo:

```
nome sobrenome
joão Silva
joão Pereira
joão Santos
Luca João
Luca Jose
```

Nesse caso a query 1 resultaria em: João Silva, João Pereira, João Santos e a query 2 seria apenas o Luca João e o Luca Jose.
Estou tentando fazer isso com PHP, um SELECT WHERE joão resolveria o problema nesse caso, porém isso teria que ser feito de forma automática, caso tivesse outros nomes ele fizesse a mesma coisa.

Comment: Posta o código que você tem.

Comment: Não possuo nenhum código no momento, isso é apenas uma idéia. Estou vendo as possibilidades para tentar organizar isso de forma viável na hora de criar o DB, no casso gostaria apenas de receber um exemplo caso isso que estou tentando fazer seja possível...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entendi que há duas colunas, uma para nome e outra para sobrenome. Estou certo?
Se sim, é possível fazer assim:

1. Faça um `SELECT DISTINCT` da coluna nome;
2. Percorra o resultado desse `SELECT` num laço e para cada registro,
   crie uma query nova com o seguinte SQL:
   *SELECT NOME FROM TABELA WHERE NOME = (Nome que está vindo do laço)*

Comment: Não sabia que havia algo do tipo no MYSQL, muito obrigado!

Comment: Só esclarecendo que o laço deve ser feito no **PHP** com o **ResultSet** da primeira **query** com o  **DISTINCT**.